# How to get upper case instead of lower case in a string without method toUppercase. P.S below

Tags: java, methods, char, uppercase, lowercase

How to get upper case instead of lower case in a string without method toUppercase, but the other symbols should not change in the string

```
   package com.telukhin.hw6;

public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    } private static String lowerCase(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch < 'z') {
                ch = ch - '32';
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: what is the int value of 'A' and what is the int value of 'a'

Comment: int value of A = 65 and a 97

Comment: So to turn 97 into 65, you need to subtract 32.. same for all lowercase

Comment: What happens if you subtract 'a' - 'A' from any lowercase letter?

Comment: Tyler, I tried but I don't understand how i can change the value

Comment: FWIW, this only works for a few lower-case letters, namely a-z.   There are a lot more letters in the world.

Comment: The method for converting to upper case should surely be called ```uppercase``` and not ```lowercase```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```
public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lowerCase("HELLO"));
    }

    private static String lowerCase(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) 
                sb.append((char)(ch+32));           
            else
                sb.append((char)ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello
```

Please check https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~pattis/15-1XX/common/handouts/ascii.html for reference.

**UPDATE:** Adding a method to convert a `String` to upper case as well

```
public class Task1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(lowerCase("HELLO"));
        System.out.println(upperCase("hello"));
    }

    private static String lowerCase(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90) //ASCII value of 'A'is 65 and that of 'Z' is 90
                sb.append((char)(ch+32));           
            else
                sb.append((char)ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    private static String upperCase(String s) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) //ASCII value of 'a'is 97 and that of 'z' is 122
                sb.append((char)(ch-32));           
            else
                sb.append((char)ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hello
HELLO
```

Comment: It's clearer to write 'A and 'Z' than 65 and 90.  But this example converts to lower case, and it looks to me that the OP asked for conversion to upper case.  It's curious he accepted it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- ASCII value of lowercase char a to z ranges from 97 to 122
- ASCII value of uppercase char A to Z ranges from 65 to 92
- For conversion we are adding 32 from the ASCII value of input char.

Add this in your if statement:

> ch = ch + 32;

Comment: Adding 32 converts 'A' to 'a', and 'a' to some C1 control character. You need to subtract 32.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this isn't homework, which the limit of not using toUppercase sort of implies, you could do this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        final String upper = toUpperCase("HELLO1234@world.CoM");

        System.out.println(upper);
    }

    private static String toUpperCase(final String s)
    {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        for(final char c : s.toCharArray())
        {
            final char upper = Character.toUpperCase(c);

            builder.append(upper);
        }

        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```

This will handle non-ascii characters. Alternatively, you can still use the 65 and 90 bit in place of Character.toUpperCase

Answer (score 0):

One more example.  This converts the string to an array of characters for working with, and then creates a new string with the result.  It seems more convenient than using charAt, StringBuilder, etc.

Like many of the other answers, valid only for the 26 letters that also occur in ASCII.

```
class Foo {

    public static String upcase(String str) {
        char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
        for (int k=0; k<arr.length; k++) {
            if (arr[k] >= 'a' && arr[k] <= 'z') {
                arr[k] -= ('a'-'A');
            }
        }
        return new String(arr);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String test = "a9z A?Z";
        System.out.println(test + " ==> " + upcase(test));
    }
}
```